# Android: findViewById() return NULL even after setContentView()

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I searched stackoverflow and found a lot of similar questions that still don't apply to mine. So, I have MainActivity with its layout in **res/layout/main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/week_summary"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/PaddedTextView"
            />
    <Button
            style="?stMainScreenPlusButton"
            android:onClick="openAddActivityScreen"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.theapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        updateWeekSummary();
    }

    public void openAddActivityScreen(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void updateWeekSummary() {
        TextView summaryView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.week_summary);

        int week_event_count = BasicStats.countAllForLastWeek();
        String week_summary;
        if (week_event_count > 0) {
            week_summary = String.format(getString(R.string.week_summary_fmt), week_event_count);
        } else {
            week_summary = getString(R.string.week_summary_empty);
        }
        summaryView.setText(week_summary);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the updateWeekSummary() method, the summaryView variable is always NULL. I found some common sources of similar errors: 
1) not calling super.onCreate() on the very first line of your Activity's onCreate method
2) calling setContentView() after a call to findViewById()
3) misspelling android:id attribute.

None of these seem to be the case, and I am totally lost now.

**UPD. As requested, the LogCat output:**

> 03-22 15:33:55.629  29404-29404/com.example.theapp W/dalvikvm﹕
>   threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41626e18)
>   03-22 15:33:55.669  29404-29404/com.example.theapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.theapp, PID: 29404
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.theapp/com.example.theapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.theapp.MainActivity.updateWeekSummary(MainActivity.java:36)
>               at com.example.theapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: The code looks great, have you checked that the name of the layout is correct and the layout contains the right information? That is the only reason to me for not finding this

Comment: It seems some problem with xml resources. start a new project and add one text view than refer it from xml and set any text then see if its working fine or not. or you can simplay download any sample project and run it.

Comment: Why did your button doesn't has id?

Comment: Yeah, it really seems to be an xml resource problem. I created an empty project with virtually the same code and ti worked. I use references extensively in order to make my app easily themeable, maybe that is the source of problems...

Comment: Anggrayudi H, I don't need an ID for the button, it just needs to call a method specified in onClick attribute

Comment: @Feantury, yes I checked the layout name, and the layout contains correct information (well, there should be an error somewhere but not that I can see it). Btw, the layout is rendered correctly in Android Studio's renderer.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind will to help! It seems like it was some Android Studio issue. I changed the TextView id and everything worked like a charm!

Comment: May be a duplicate id or you need to clean project.